# EF Core Not Updating Foreign Key Items Correctly

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am trying to update a `user` and their corresponding `items` but I am getting strange behavior.  More specifically, the `user` is updating, but the `items` are being added to the `items` table and the previous `items` that were already present in the table, have a `UserId` of `null`, and the new `items` have the updated `UserId`.

I've tried various things like including `UserId` and `ItemId` in my REST call but this results in a `System.InvalidOperationException` for the `items`.  However, adding a `user` and their corresponding `items` to the tables works fine.

```
public HttpStatusCode UpdateUsersAndItems(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (MyContext myContext = _myContext as MyContext)
        {
            User updateUser = myContext?.Users?.Include(i => i.Items).FirstOrDefault(u => u != null && u.UserName == user.UserName);

            if(updateUser != null)
            {
                updateUser.UserName = user.UserName;
                updateUser.Dob = user.Dob;
                updateUser.Location = user.Location;
                updateUser.Items = user.Items;

                myContext?.Users?.Update(updateUser);

                int changes = myContext.SaveChanges();

                if (changes > 0)
                {
                    return HttpStatusCode.Created;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
}

namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Dob { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Items> Items { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace TestWebApplication.Database
{
    public class Items
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Item { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int? UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Rest call

```
{
    "username": "xxx",
    "dob": "xxx",
    "location": "xxx",
    "items":[{
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx"
        },
        {
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx"
        },
        {
        "item": "xxx",
        "category": "xxx",
        "type": "xxx"
        }]
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that when you save, EF trashes the userid of all existing users in the table, and only saves the ones you just linked up?

Comment: You are replacing the entire `Items` collection here: `updateUser.Items = user.Items;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through each item, and change its properties.

Something like this.

```
       using (MyContext myContext = _myContext as MyContext)
        {
            User updateUser = myContext?.Users?.Include(i => i.Items).FirstOrDefault(u => u != null && u.Id == user.Id);

            if(updateUser != null)
            {
                updateUser.UserName = user.UserName;
                updateUser.Dob = user.Dob;
                updateUser.Location = user.Location;
                foreach( var userItem in user.Items )
                {
                   var updateItem = updateUser.Items.SingleOrDefault( i => i.Id == userItem.Id );
                   if( updateItem == null )
                   {
                     updateItem = new Items {
                       Type = userItem.Type,
                       Category = userItem.Category
                     };
                     updateUser.Items.Add(updateItem);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                     updateItem.Type = userItem.Type;
                     updateItem.Category = userItem.Category;
                   }
                }


                int changes = myContext.SaveChanges();

                if (changes > 0)
                {
                    return HttpStatusCode.Created;
                }
            }
        }
```

*i can't see how you uniquely identity your items, but don't expose you primary keys to the frontend (web)*

Comment: the correct would be `updateUser.Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == userItem.Id)` but i don't know if you have the `Id` on the `User` type?

Comment: Awesome!  It works, thank you.  Please ignore my last comment (which I deleted) as I didn't at first understand the code!  I have changed it back to `SingleOrDefault` and it still works.  I do have an `id` on my `user` class, unless I am reading your comment incorrectly.  Another thing you cleared up for me is using `ids` in rest calls and web - great!